# Android Broadcast receiver not executed on application close

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have an android application, where I schedule to an event (location update) to be executed in the future using Alarm manager. The scheduled event executes as expected as long as the application runs in the foreground or in the background. But once I force close the application under task manager or when android system kills the application due to memory issue when the app is at background, I am no longer able to receive the broadcast from the alarm manager.

As suggested by various posts and blogs i tried using 
    1) Intent.Flag_Include_Stopped_Packages
    2) receiver android:process=":remote" in manifest
    3) receiver android:exported="true" in manifest

In Service:

```
Intent locationIntent = new Intent("com.dummy.intent");  
locationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
locationIntent.putExtra(LocationLibraryConstants.LOCATION_BROADCAST_EXTRA_LOCATIONINFO, locationInfo);
context.sendBroadcast(locationIntent, "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
```

In Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".NearestStationBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="true" 
  android:process=":remote">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.dummy.intent" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 5):

> But once I force close the application under task manager or when android system kills the application due to memory issue when the app is at background, I am no longer able to receive the broadcast from the alarm manager.

These have nothing to do with each other, so if you have been simulating "when android system kills the application due to memory issue" by using Force Stop, that is your problem. An app that has been force-stopped through Settings has its alarms removed, among other things. A better way to simulate your process being terminated is to terminate it from DDMS.

> 1) Intent.Flag_Include_Stopped_Packages 2) receiver android:process=":remote" in manifest 3) receiver android:exported="true" in manifest

None of those are related to your problem, and `android:exported="true"` (and your use of an `<intent-filter>`) raises security issues, as now anyone can cause your `BroadcastReceiver` to be run at any time, for any reason.

[Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Scheduled) that successfully processes alarm events, even after the process has been terminated by DDMS.

Comment: But I am not simulating this scenario on emulator. I am installing the app on the actual device. After I start the alarm for listening location and when the app moves to in-active state (by opening other apps) after few mins as I open few other apps android system stops my location app from background. Then at alarm interval service re-starts and sends the intent of the location update info. But broadcast receiver which is defined in app manifest does not trigger. The above works perfectly when the app is available on background. Hope you got my point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the sample, was struggling get this up since few days, thanks for saving my day!

Comment: Not related though, but I have an issue with intent.getStringExtra while using the same receiver class for different alarms, if I use different classes no issues, something silly happening, but i end up adding more receiver classes

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your app in the Android Settings > Protected Apps section on the phone. This lets the user control which apps to allow running in the background.

You could also write a service to listen to the location broadcasts which will run in the background without problem if you get the necessary permissions.