# Broadcast receiver is not working in lollipop after application closed from task manager

Tags: java, android, xml

This is the Broadcastreceiver. This code is working in the kitkat and jeallyBean. In this we simple receive the notification  of incoming message. It shows notification when any message come in mobile.

```
    public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    Notification myNotication;
    NotificationManager nm;
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        nm = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String compnum=phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);



                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                    toast.show();
                    if(senderNum.equals(compnum))
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(context,"Come in the loop",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);

                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent2, 0);

                        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

                        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                        builder.setTicker("this is ticker text");
                        builder.setContentTitle("WhatsApp Notification");
                        builder.setContentText("You have a new message");
                        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pretty_bullet);
                        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                        builder.setOngoing(true);
                        builder.setSubText("This is subtext...");   
                        builder.setNumber(100);
                        builder.build();

                        myNotication = builder.getNotification();
                        nm.notify(50, myNotication);
                    }
                } 
            } 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }  
}
```

In the manifest i declare

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms">
            <intent-filter
                android:priority="1">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This is not working when application is closed from the task manager. But it works on the jallybean. I want to show the notification whether application is open or closed.

Comment: [You can check this link. As it has same problem and also answers which may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39160320/broadcast-receiver-not-working-when-application-close-from-task-manager-in-lolli)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following,

[Android Broadcast receiver not executed on application close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273168/android-broadcast-receiver-not-executed-on-application-close)

I also think that you might want to read up on how to set the priority. Please read the following,

> **AndroidManifestIntentFilter_priority**
>
> int AndroidManifestIntentFilter_priority Specify the relative
>   importance or ability in handling a particular Intent. For receivers,
>   this controls the order in which they are executed to receive a
>   broadcast (note that for asynchronous broadcasts, this order is
>   ignored). For activities, this provides information about how good an
>   activity is handling an Intent; when multiple activities match an
>   intent and have different priorities, only those with the higher
>   priority value will be considered a match.
>
> Only use if you really need to impose some specific order in which the
>   broadcasts are received, or want to forcibly place an activity to
>   always be preferred over others. The value is a single integer, with
>   higher numbers considered to be better.
>
> Must be an integer value, such as "100".
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol priority.
>
> Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002)