# Broadcast receiver not working when application close from task manager in lollipop

Tags: android

I create Broadcast receiver for receive sms . It works only application is open. When we remove application from task manager it cant works. It works fine in jelly bean, kitkat but not working in the lollipop version.

```
    public class MobiricReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);


                    // Show Alert
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                            "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                    toast.show();

                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }
}
```

**Decalaration** in **Menifest**

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.admin.broadcast_demo1">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".MobiricReceiver"
            >
            <intent-filter
                android:priority="1">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What device are you testing with?

Comment: BroadcastReciever must be working even after app is closed from Task Manager, but this issue may be with `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` action. Which device are you testing?

Comment: I got the solution for this. Simple put this in activity . android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true" .Application never kill. I test on lollipop 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple solution.Add this in Menifest--> activity tag

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true">
        </activity>
```

On the Back press of Button please finish activity with this code

```
 if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
                            {
                                getActivity().finishAndRemoveTask();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                getActivity().finish();
                            }
```