# Clipboard clip change listener not working when app closed in Android Oreo

Tags: android, service, clipboard, clipboardmanager

I was following below tutorial to check copy text event while the app is background or closed.

https://github.com/twaddington/Android-Clipboard-Monitor/blob/master/src/com/example/clipboardmonitor/service/ClipboardMonitorService.java

Now It's not working when the app is closed in android oreo. Is there any alternate of ClipboardMonitorService as background service is removed after API 26.

Comment: sir are u using broadcast receiver to call service ?

Comment: I have started this service in two conditions 1- when the app opens first time I started this service in OnCreate of the home screen. 2 - When phone restart I started this service using the BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast receiver.

Comment: ok i will post answer

Comment: sure, I am waiting.

Comment: sir i recently faced this issue and i solve it using this i hope its helps i will posted my answer

Comment: Hi @Shamsul I have the exact same problem. did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Upsilon42, no solution found yet, If you found any solution then please update here.

Answer (score 1):

As part of Android Oreo, there were several restrictions placed on background services. I don't think your problem can be solved. Please [refer this post](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-background-execution-limits-on-android-oreo-ab384762a66c) to know more. All the different types of execution models are explained in that post. I know I wasn't much help, but I figured i'll share what I know.

Answer (score 0):

Ref to [Broadcast receiver is not working in lollipop after application closed from task manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000044/broadcast-receiver-is-not-working-in-lollipop-after-application-closed-from-task)

Please see the following,

[Android Broadcast receiver not executed on application close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273168/android-broadcast-receiver-not-executed-on-application-close)

I also think that you might want to read up on how to set the priority. Please read the following,

> AndroidManifestIntentFilter_priority
>
> int AndroidManifestIntentFilter_priority Specify the relative
>   importance or ability in handling a particular Intent. For receivers,
>   this controls the order in which they are executed to receive a
>   broadcast (note that for asynchronous broadcasts, this order is
>   ignored). For activities, this provides information about how good an
>   activity is handling an Intent; when multiple activities match an
>   intent and have different priorities, only those with the higher
>   priority value will be considered a match.
>
> Only use if you really need to impose some specific order in which the
>   broadcasts are received, or want to forcibly place an activity to
>   always be preferred over others. The value is a single integer, with
>   higher numbers considered to be better.
>
> Must be an integer value, such as "100".
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol priority.
>
> Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002)

As suggested by various posts and blogs i tried using

> 1. Intent.Flag_Include_Stopped_Packages
> 2. receiver android:process=":remote" in manifest
> 3. receiver android:exported="true" in manifest

```
In Manifest:

<receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="true" 
  android:process=":remote">
</receiver>
```

**And According to [Android 8.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes)**

**Background execution limits**

As one of the changes that Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces to improve battery life, when your app enters the cached state, with no active components, the system releases any wakelocks that the app holds.

In addition, to improve device performance, the system limits certain behaviors by apps that are not running in the foreground. Specifically:

- Apps that are running in the background now have limits on how freely
  they can access background services.
- Apps cannot use their manifests to register for most implicit
  broadcasts (that is, broadcasts that are not targeted specifically at
  the app). By default, these restrictions only apply to apps that
  target O. However, users can enable these restrictions for any app
  from the Settings screen, even if the app has not targetted O.

Android 8.0 (API level 26) also includes the following changes to specific methods:

- The startService() method now throws an IllegalStateException if an
  app targeting Android 8.0 tries to use that method in a situation
  when it isn't permitted to create background services.
- The new Context.startForegroundService() method starts a foreground
  service. The system allows apps to call
  Context.startForegroundService() even while the app is in the
  background. However, the app must call that service's
  startForeground() method within five seconds after the service is
  created.

For more information, see Background Execution Limits.

[**ClipboardManager**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager)

Interface to the clipboard service, for placing and retrieving text in the global clipboard.

> The ClipboardManager API itself is very simple: it consists of methods
>   to atomically get and set the current primary clipboard data. That
>   data is expressed as a ClipData object, which defines the protocol for
>   data exchange between applications.

For More Info Please Visit Once https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager

Comment: service is running perfectly before Android 8.0(Oreo). After Android 8.0 android removes the concept of background service due to security reason, android recommended JobSchedulerin the place of background service but my requirement is not fulfilled with JobScheduler.

Comment: My requirement is that if someone copies some text in your device I want to get that text whether my app is open or closed. I don't want to show a foreground service for forever on the notification bar.

Comment: @Shamsul right sir but what about service if service is not running then its never call your listener which is defined in your service

Comment: be sure your service is running

Comment: You are right, but I am searching for any alternate so that I can listen copy text event on Android Oreo.

Comment: @Shamsul you mean any other way to listen copy text event ?

Comment: Yes, I am searching any other way.

Comment: may there is not other way to listen

Comment: please read once https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager

Comment: @Shamsul Have you find any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

JobScheduler is the best alternative. You can set a time interval of 15 minutes and it will re-schedule your job after every 15 minutes. I know this will not work like service but you can make use of it by optimizing it properly.

Comment: please explain your answer with the snippet. So that it can be helpful for other users. It is good practice if you provide the code or logic.